# ZIMPL: Variables with two indices

Tags: scip

i have started to use the zpl.format to solve a linear program with scip.

In my linear programm there are variables with 2 indices. Can I rebuild this in the zpl.format like `var b[x,t]` or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

You index with a two dimension set. 
Set I := { <1,2>, <2,3>, <5,7> };

var b[I];

for  in I do ...